# How do i prevent duplicate insertion from one table to another at client side using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my table code.The data gets inserted from another table into this table but with duplicates.I want to insert rows without duplicates.Do i need to use array and certain other javascript methods?

```
function onSelect(code,name,phone) {

    var newRow = document.all("listtable").insertRow(-1);

    Cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    Cell1.innerHTML = code;

    Cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    Cell2.innerHTML = name;

    Cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    Cell3.innerHTML = phone;

    Cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    Cell4.innerHTML = "<font onclick=\"removeRow(this)\" style=\"color:red;cursor:pointer;\"> X </font>";

}
```

Comment: What sort of DOM node is "listtable"? and what do you mean by "with duplicates"? Please show same sample output. Does the "other" table also have these duplicates - and now you want to eliminate them?

Comment: The "listtable" is the id given to this table for displaying it.The other table does not have duplicate entries but when i select them and display these three columns in this table ,duplicate entries also get inserted.Duplicate rows shouldnt be inserted .Incase we try to insert them a message should be displayed saying already inserted.This happens at the client side.It has nothing to with databse